# PackageNotInstalledError: Anaconda / JuliaPro clash

Tags: anaconda, julia

I recent installed JuliaPro to try Julia. Upon trying to get back to working in Python and updating Anaconda, I get the following error.

```
(base) C:\>conda update anaconda
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3
  package name: anaconda
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, have a look at the `enviroments.txt` file at `%HOMEPATH%\.conda`

Giving full path to Anaconda often solves the problem (on my machine Anaconda is installed to `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`):

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda
```

When using Jupyter check also the configuration at `%HOMEPATH%\.jupyter`

hope that helps.